# Execute sql CREATE TABLE query in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I need to dynamically create a table using a Java method and tranform all its rows into a list of Mapping class objects. The questions are..

- Is there a way to execute CREATE TABLE query dynamically?
- I saw some examples using doInHibernate() but it didn't work when I tried it. Can I do this without the particular method?

Answer (score 5):

You could just execute a native sql query: `session.createSQLQuery("create table .....").executeUpdate();`  where "session" is your Hibernate session.

If you already have the mapping files, though, you can just set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property in your hibernate configuration to generate the schema based on the mapping files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
session.createSQLQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

another possibility would be:

```
createStatement().execute(someddl);
```